# biblatex and pgfplots

Tags: biblatex, pgfplots, incompatibility

I'm using pgfplots to plot some graph of data I stored in a file (a lot of data points). If I charge the `bibtex` package, I obtains the following error:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=300000].
```

**Is there any kind of incompatibility between biblatex and pgfplots?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Incompatibility reasons for packages usually does not show itself with memory problems.

Your problem is due to the fact that `biblatex` requires more memory space than usual `bibtex` packages, such as natbib. You should know that `biblatex` is a *big* package.
You should simply increase your memory size which is dependent on your distribution.

The manual for `pgfplots` is useful as it has a section regarding this issue. See section *Memory Limits* or search around for increasing the memory size for your distro, MikTeX, TeXLive, MacTeX, etc.

Comment: And the crystal ball goes to....